How to define preprocessor symbols using devenv.com command line arguments?
Following this post, I want to add global preprocessor directives (equivalent to #define in every .cs file) using devenv.com command line arguments.
I already know two ways to achieve this:

Using MSBuild:

msbuild.exe MyProject.csproj /p:DefineConstants="MYMACRO;TRACE"


Adding to the .csproj file:

<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants>MYMACRO;TRACE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>

However, I specifically want to learn how to do this with devenv.com command line arguments. When I try:
devenv.com MyProject.csproj /Build "Release|AnyCPU" /p:DefineConstants="MYMACRO;TRACE"

I get an error:
Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : MYMACRO;TRACE.

Minimal Working Example
MacroTest.csproj:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{8A9C5693-0BB4-4E15-9D6A-C3E6E6B42B80}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MacroTest</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MacroTest</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>

Program.cs:
using System;

namespace MacroTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if MYMACRO
            Console.WriteLine("MYMACRO is defined!");
#else
            Console.WriteLine("MYMACRO is NOT defined!");
#endif
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2019 (Version 16.11.42).
Is there a way to define preprocessor symbols using devenv.com command line arguments? The /Build command help doesn't mention anything about passing properties, but maybe there's another switch I'm missing?

deven.com /Build - Builds a solution or project using a specified solution configuration file. msbuild.exe - can include several switches to specify various aspects of the process. I don't think you can just replace one with another.

You can see in the devenv command line documentation that there is no /p option, which explains why your attempt to use it is reported as invalid. The documentation recommends that if you want to build, use msbuild rather than devenv, probably for this very reason. devenv is not as configurable as msbuild. (You can hack it by creating a Directory.Build.props that defines the symbols.)

@RaymondChen true. This question is just out of curiosity not necessity. Although I usually prefer devenv.com over msbuild.exe in mt cmd batch files because the output is much more concise and readable.

@Sinatr I am not sure if I fully understand you. I can build a .csproj file with devenv.com as well.

I mean their purpose is different. You can't debug with msbuild, nor you should expect to replace msbuild with deven.com /Build (as you do). It's simply a wrong tool.

@Sinatr As said above, this post is just to learn and does not necessarily have immediate practical purposes. It is not about the best way to do a certain thing but to learn how a certain thing, in this case devenv.com, functions.

Inspired by this post, I realized that I can define preprocessor symbols for devenv.com builds by setting the DefineConstants environment variable before running the build:
set "DefineConstants=MYMACRO;TRACE"
devenv.com MyProject.csproj /Build "Release|AnyCPU"

To remove these definitions later:
set "DefineConstants="

This approach works because MSBuild (which devenv.com uses under the hood) respects environment variables for property values. It's similar to using /p:DefineConstants with msbuild.exe but works within Visual Studio's command-line constraints.
Note: This method persists only in the current command prompt session. Each new command prompt will start with clean environment variables.

This works because MSBuild treats environment variables as properties. https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build

@DrewNoakes this is very interesting and can b both a very useful thing or a very difficult thing to debug. It is much easier, IMHO, to edit a cmd batch file that calls the devenv.com/msbuild.exe than the convoluted XML .csproj file. But if there is something in the environment variables that is causing a certain behaviour that is very difficult to reproduce.

"convoluted .csproj" - I read this as you are working alone and using same pc for development and deployment. Once you are in team and have dedicated build server you will see how "convoluted .csproj" suddenly become your best friend ;)

I'm curious why you use devenv /build vs msbuild directly. The latter would bypass your problem.

@DrewNoakes there is no problem really. I could use msbuild.exe if I wanted to and nothing would stop me. the whole question is just a learning exercise for me. Nevertheless, devenv.com outputs are much cleaner and less cluttered. on the negative side, it is also less capable and quite often slower.

To reduce clutter in the output of msbuild, try using the -tl argument (terminal logger).

@DrewNoakes I didn't know that. Thanks.

@DrewNoakes I get MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch. Switch: -tl

@DrewNoakes I could get less cluttered output with /verbosity:minimal /nologo /fileLogger

What version of MSBuild are you using? It works in 17.12.

The docs actually say it's --tl. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#options. Note that terminal logger was made the default in the MSBuild that ships with .NET 9's SDK (which you can use on downlever versions of .NET too) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/9.0/terminal-logger
